# Rails 4 | How do you not show URL of a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

What is the best practice with links inside of a web app?

For example; I have modals, etc. which are currently anchor tags, however when hovering over they say #create, #update, etc. I don't want the user to see this. Is there a way I can avoid showing that without making the anchor tag a button tag?

How do you guys normally deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad...

Answer is very simple: use JavaScript and catch click event on link.

See example below:

```html
<script>
  function showModal(modalName) {
    // here will be modal show function
    alert('Showing modal: '+modalName);
    return false;
  }
</script>

<a href="" onclick="return showModal('create')">
  CREATE SOMETHING
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create modals not like site URLs but like parts of your basic views/pages (load view in view) and you can create methods for your modal views in the controller which load view/page where you load and view/modal (this is just 1 way) . The pattern of creating the URLs is (I think) same for almost all MVC frameworks - yoursite.com/controller/action/id.